# timer does not fire when combined with a backgroundworker in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

I have an asp.net webpage that uses a "backgroundworker" to interact with a class that does time-consuming work.  The backgroundworker fires a routine in the webpage called "worker_ProgressChanged".

This works, and I store the progress that is reported in a session variable.

But now I have to tell my webpage about the progress.  So I did the following.  I put a timer in an update panel, and I expect it to fire a timer event in the code-behind. In that timer-event, I want to retrieve the session variable, and update a label (that is also in the updatepanel)  Without the backgroundworker, the timer does fire.  But with the background worker, it does not.

something about a progress event firing simply turns off the ability of the timer to fire or to find its event-handler.

Any one have ideas on this?   HERE IS THE CODE:

```
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <center>
    <table>
        <tr><td>
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
              <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLog" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5"  Width="550px" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" BackColor="sandybrown"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false"></asp:Timer><br />
                  <asp:Label ID="Labelerror2" SkinID="errorlabel" runat="server"  />
               </ContentTemplate>

           </asp:UpdatePanel>



            </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please enter the entire path of the video (on your PC) to upload to Azure" SkinID="ordinarylabel"></asp:Label></td></tr>
           <tr><td style="text-align:center">
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFileName" runat="server" Width="273px"></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorFilename"   ControlToValidate="TextBoxFileName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter a file name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


               </td></tr>
           <tr><td style="text-align:center">

               <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" />

               <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
               </td></tr>
    </table>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelError" SkinID="errorlabel" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ClientIDMode="Static" />
         <asp:Label ID="LabelExperiment" SkinID="errorlabel" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        </center>

===================
Imports System.ComponentModel
Partial Class zOwner_UploadAzure
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub ButtonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmit.Click
        Dim strName As String
        strName = Me.TextBoxFileName.Text.Trim

        If Not ClassStrings.IsValidFileName(strName, True) Then
            Me.LabelError.Text = "Error, the filename you supplied does not fit the Windows format of filenames."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Me.TextBoxLog.Visible = True
        AzureNameSpaceGid.Azurex.userpcfilename = strName
        AzureNameSpaceGid.Azurex.username = Membership.GetUser.UserName
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker()
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf AzureNameSpaceGid.Azurex.UploadFile

        AddHandler worker.ProgressChanged, New ProgressChangedEventHandler(AddressOf worker_ProgressChanged)
        Me.Labelerror2.Text = "Starting..."
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        Session("hitsubmit") = True
        '  AzureNameSpaceGid.Azurex.UploadFile(strName)
        '  Me.LabelError.Text = "The Upload to Azure is complete - <a href='addvideo500.aspx'>click here</a> to add the video to rateforsuccess."
    End Sub



    Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Dim obj As Object
        obj = e.UserState
        Dim strMessage As String
        strMessage = obj.ToString
        If strMessage.StartsWith("URL_") Then
            Session("azureurl") = strMessage.Substring(4)
            Response.Redirect("addvideo500.aspx")
        ElseIf strMessage.StartsWith("LOGMESSAGE_") Then

            Session("strerror") = Session("strerror") & vbCrLf & "<br />" & strMessage.Substring(11)
        Else

            Session("strprogress") = Session("strprogress") & vbCrLf & strMessage
        End If

        ' LabelError.Text = ("Progress: " & e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%")
    End Sub


    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ' Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Session("hitsubmit") = False
            Session("strprogress") = ""
            Session("strerror") = ""
        End If
        If Session("hitsubmit") Then
            Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
            Me.TextBoxLog.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Me.TextBoxLog.Text = Session("strprogress")
        Me.Labelerror2.Text = Session("strError")
        Me.LabelExperiment.Text = Me.LabelExperiment.Text & "***"
    End Sub
End Class
=======================
```

There is not enough room to put in the actual azure class.
Thanks

Comment: "something about a progress event firing simply turns off the ability of the timer to fire or to find its event-handler." I find that unlikely. In any event, it's impossible to confirm or deny unless you provide us some code.

Comment: OK, I'll insert code in the original post by editing it.  What I'm saying is true, I've tested all the steps, adding piece by piece.

Comment: @JimMischel: I've inserted as much code as I could fit, the actual azure library was too large.